# how to update weight in database

Tags: c#

```
private void btn_Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "update MyWeight set Weight='" + txt_Weight.Text + "'where Name='" + txt_Name.Text + "'";
    string a = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    con.Close();

    if (a != null)
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        display_data();
        MessageBox.Show("Weight updated successfuly!!!");
    }
    else
    {
        con.Close();

        display_data();
        MessageBox.Show("Not updated!!!");
    }
}
```

I tried to update the weight into the database, but the database keeps saying that it is not updated.

Comment: When you debug, what is the actual runtime value of `cmd.CommandText`?  Does it match what you expect?  (Note: Your code is *wide open* to **SQL injection**.  You should be using query parameters instead of directly concatenating user input.)  What is the observed runtime result of `cmd.ExecuteScalar()`?  Why are you casting it to a `string`?  (And why are you executing the command *again* on success?  Did you not trust that the success was successful?  If not, why would you trust that it was successful the second time?)

Comment: The database isn't saying anything. That message is the one you're telling the application to display when `a` is `null`. Why would you expect it to be anything else? What are you expecting that `ExecuteScalar` call to return and why?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
        bool updated;
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "update MyWeight set Weight=@Weight where Name=@Name";


            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Weight", txt_Weight.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Name", txt_Name.Text));

            updated = (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 1);

            con.Close();
        }
            

        if (updated)
        {
            display_data();
            MessageBox.Show("Weight updated successfuly!!!");
        }
        else
        {
            display_data();
            MessageBox.Show("Not updated!!!");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It makes more sense to use `ExecuteNonQuery` for update operations in general because you don't expect any results.

Have you checked the table to see if it did update the row?

Why are you executing the same command with `ExecuteNonQuery` inside the if statement?